# Can I use 'You felt stressful'? Can I use this expression in some situations?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

I know I have to use **"I am stressed" not "stressful"** but I have some confusing expressions.

1. In many stressful situations, can I use **"I felt stressful to something"**?
2. If something makes me stressed, can I use **"I felt stressful (to something)"**?

Comment: An *action* might be stressful, and the person doing it feels stressed.

Comment: Hello, NDBRO. Do any dictionaries include a definition of 'stressful' meaning 'stressed'?

Comment: You're probably confused because you think stressful would mean "full of stress" in the sense "suffering from stress". But it doesn't; it means "causing lots of stress". Sometimes words don't mean what the individual elements suggest. Similarly, "wonderful" and "awful" mean causing wonder and awe; while "thoughtful" describes a person "having lots of thoughts (for others)" not "causing lots of thoughts". This question can be answered with a dictionary, so it's not really valid to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

To say that something is "stressful" is simply to say that it causes you stress. Indeed, Oxford Learner's Dictionaries online gives the definition as "causing a lot of worry".

E.g. This job is so stressful

By contrast, "stressed" describes a feeling of stress that you feel, as a result of experiencing difficulties in life.

E.g. I'm stressed, because I have no money

You can't describe a person as stressful, because it would mean that they **cause** stress, which is the opposite of what you mean.

In theory it should be possible to say that someone is stressful in the sense that they cause you stress, but this doesn't really happen in practice. You'd be more likely to say "it's so stressful working with her" or, informally, "she really stresses me out".